# Hard Disk Reference in Shell Scripts /dev/sda & /dev/nvme0

Tags: command-line, scripts, hard-drive, nvme

I have two types of computers, on one hard disk type is NVME while other is generic hard disk.

I have a script to format the disk and then clean /wipe the disk with Scrub.

```
sudo mkfs -F /dev/nvme0n1

sudo scrub /dev/nvme0n1
```

On generic hard disk (non-NVME disks), I have to modify the code as:

```
sudo mkfs -F /dev/sda

sudo scrub /dev/sda
```

These laptops may or may not contain an operating system by default.

I am trying to find a way to avoid having two scripts (1) for NVME (2) for standard drives.

In other words, I want to skip the "sda" or "nvme0n1" so script is general, can run on either disk types if it's possible somehow?

**Update: 1st Nov 2023.**

[image: lsblk -d -o name NAME loop0 loop1 loop2 loop3 loop4 loop5 loop6 loop7 loop8 loop9 loop10 loop11 loop12 loop13 loop14 sda sdb nvme0n1]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "disk 0" or "primary hard disk"? The disk that the system boots from? The disk(s) that contains the partition(s) mounted on `/`? The former may not be the same as the latter, and indeed the latter can be multiple disks.

Comment: Use `lsblk` to list your devices - and use the ID provided there. My NVME drive is named `nvme0n1`.

Comment: Correct, the first disk /physical disk (disk 0 in Microsoft Windows).

Instead of referring to *sda* or *nvme0n1* I am looking for a more general approach (if possible), so I can modify the script.

I am not asking how to get the device ID, rather asking how to write a script /reference in a script that work on both disk types.

Comment: Please explain what your final objective is. There isn't really a concept of "primary" hard disk in the Linux world, not like there is in Windows. So this feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). If you explain what the actual final objective is, we can help you achieve it. Do you want to know what disk your main `/` partition is on, perhaps? Or the drive where the bootloader is installed? What do you want to do to the "primary" partition once you find it, why are you looking for it?

Comment: **sudo mkfs -F /dev/nvme0n1** >>> This works fine on NVME drives.
However, above code fails when the disk is non-NVME disk.
**sudo mkfs -F /dev/sda** <<< I have to modify the code.

Similarly, when I use the scrub to wipe the disk, I have to use the following:

**sudo scrub /dev/sda**
**sudo scrub /dev/nvme0n1**

Again, I want to get rid of writing /specifying nvme0n1 or sda etc. 
Clean the disk0 /or primary disk, whatever if nvme0n1 or sda.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the extra information. But, again, you need to explain what disk you are targeting. There is no concept of "primary", really, so which disk is it you want to look at? How would you choose it? Is this a script that will be run on a computer with no OS? With an OS?  Is "primary" the disk which has the partition `/` is mounted on? What if this is an LVM? What of they are mounted remote partitions on a diskless server? Please [edit] your question and explain what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: I have updated the question now.

Comment: I don't think that it is a really good idea to script such things since it can be pretty destructive. However, you can use an if-statement to check if a file `/dev/sda` or `/dev/nvme0n1` exists.

Comment: I'm sorry but this still doesn't make sense. Why would you create a filesystem on `/dev/sda`. Do you perhaps mean `/dev/sda1`? What is the mkfs doing? I don't see an `-F` option, what does that do? What file system type are you trying to create? How do you know which disk you want to use? How do you know if you want `nvme0n1` or `nvme0n2` for example? Are you just looking for the `/` partition? If you want to generalize something, you need to tell us what the general principle is. So, again: how do you, as a human, choose the disk?

Comment: @user68186 do you have an example of If-then?

Comment: @terdon wondering what you are keep saying it does not make sense etc. Question is simple, all I asked how to reference hard disk in a script regardless of disk type.
If it's complex for you to understand, please do not reply.

Comment: I am just trying to help. As you can see two people have downvoted (I have not), and two have upvoted my comments. So I am not alone in finding this confusing. I have asked you several times to explain which disk you want to target since there is no such ting as the "primary" in Linux, I have asked if you just want to target the disk containing the `/` partition, but you have refused to explain. So if you no longer need my help, that is absolutely fine. I will just downvote and vote to close as unclear instead of trying to help clarify.

Comment: @terdon Strange, I need to clean the disk. The main disk on the computer (not partition). Purpose is to clean /delete all partitions and data and then use scrub.

generic hard disk = /dev/sda
NVME = /dev/nvmeon1

On different computers the disk is different, I am trying to figure out if I can have a script that works on both disk types.

For me it's pretty clear and should be understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to securely wipe the internal SSD/HDD of multiple computers after booting from an USB that runs the full version of Ubuntu. The full version allows installing additional software, while the live installation USB does not.

## Step 1: Install `nvme-cli`

This utility will allow you to securely erase NVME drives without damaging them. Open a terminal and enter:

```
sudo apt install nvme-cli
```

## Step 2: Write a bash script

Create a plain text file called `squeakyclean` in the folder `$HOME/bin` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Purpose: find if there are any sata or nvme drives and take different 
# action on the each such drive
while IFS= read -r line; do
case $line in
    NAME | loop*)
    ;;
    sd?)
        echo "Found disk /dev/$line:"
        lsblk /dev/"$line"
        while true; do
        read -p "Do you want to scrub $line? (y/n) " yn < /dev/tty
            case $yn in
                y)
                    echo sudo scrub /dev/"$line"
                    echo " "
                    break
                ;;
                n)
                    echo "keeping $line"
                    echo " "
                    break
                ;;
                *) echo "invalid response";;
            esac
        done    
    ;;
    nvme[0-9]n[1-9])
        echo "Found disk /dev/$line:"
        lsblk /dev/"$line"
        while true; do
        read -p "Do you want to format $line? (y/n) " yn < /dev/tty
            case $yn in
                y)
                    echo sudo nvme format -s1 /dev/"$line"
                    echo " "
                    break
                ;;
                n)
                    echo "keeping $line"
                    echo " "
                    break
                ;;
                *) echo "invalid response";;
            esac
        done    
    ;;
    *)
        echo "$line found doing nothing"
    ;;      
    esac
done < <( lsblk -d -o name )
```

Save the file and make it executable.

**Note:** this assumes all the SATA drives are HDDs. You should probably use a different utility like `hdparm` for scrubbing SATA SSDs.

### The Logic

First, the script uses the `lsblk` command to list all the internal and external disks. This list may look like:

```
NAME
sda
sdb
sdc
nvme0n1
nvme0n2
nvme0n3
```

Second, the script asks if you want to scrub the first SATA disk, `sda`. You have to enter either `y` or `n`. Then it does the same thing for the second SATA disk `sdb` etc.

Third, the script asks if you want to securely format the first NVMe disk called `nvme0n1` if it exists. You have to enter either `y` or `n`. Then it does the same thing for the second NVMe disk `nvme0n1` etc.

Finally, for any other disks found, it lists them.

### Test

Run the script as and see what it outputs. This will tell you which disks it has found and which will be scrubbed. If your USB drive is recognized as `/dev/sda` then you have to change the script so that it does not erase your USB drive.

## Step 3: Execute!

When you are ready, remove the `echo` before `sudo` in the two lines of the script.

### Warning: Executing this script will delete everything in your computer!

Boot the computer you want to clean using the USB with the full install of Ubuntu.

Open a terminal and type `squeakyclean`. You will be asked to enter your sudo password when needed.

Hope this helps

Comment: THANKS. Your script did the work. Now I can modify my script to to use NVME-CLI for NVM disks and hdparm or shred for HDDs. (In past I was maintaining different files for NVME and HDDs).

Comment: Done, wish you a nice day ahead.

Comment: Problem accrued ... on NVME machine, it has erased the USB stick which was recognized as /dev/sda. What could be possible work-around to handle this issue?

Comment: THANKS for making modifications.
On SATA Disks >> Worked fine, /dev/sda is erased.
on NVMe Disk >> Still the same results i.e., /dev/sda is erased instead of the NVMe drive.

Comment: @user1737015 I have added added a Y/N confirmation so that it does not erase the drive you don't want to erase.

Comment: @ user68186, I think I didn't get your last updated script as the latest script I have from you is from 20th October.

Comment: @user1737015 Sorry about that. Fixed it.

Comment: @ user68186, I just updated the question with todays comment that on I have NVME0n1 , sda and sdb all 3 drive names in my system. That could be the reason why your previous script failed?
NVME0N1 is the actual hard disk, sda is the USB stick I am booting from and sdb is assigned to the card reader drive (which will be empty always).

Comment: @user1737015 I edited the code so that loop devices are ignored. Now I know why the October 20 version didn't work. This version should be generic enough for any PC.

Comment: @ user68186
Will you revert the script again to eliminate the need to pressing Y before proceeding or? Or something else needs to do for machines with card reader slots? –

Comment: @user1737015 I don't know how to take into account for the card reader slot. It is difficult to write a script that will work with all possible combinations of USB, car reader, HDD, SSD, etc. I think the Y/N approach is better.

Comment: thanks for your support in this matter.
I will check different options or will stick on manual process, i.e. separate script for SSD and NVM, Thanks again.